# Magic Packet over Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, wake-on-lan

I have an Ubuntu box that I can wake on lan (WOL) in my local network.

My router setup is as follows:

ISP > Modem > Router > Ubuntu box

I am not able to wake the Ubuntu box from outside my network, although I have forwarded port 7 and 9 (both UDP and TCP) **in the router** to the ubuntu box.

Am I forgetting something? Should I change modem settings in order to get WOL-over-ethernet working?

Thanks in advance,

M0s..

Answer (score 0):

When the computer is asleep, it cannot reply to the router's ARP requests, so you must either add a static ARP entry into the router, or forward the packets to the *subnet broadcast* address. (It doesn't have to be port 7 or 9; any UDP port will work fine.)

Also make sure that your "Wake on LAN" tool is sending the magic packets to the right address.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you get me started on how to forward the packets to the subnet broadcast address? Thank you!

Comment: @M0sthated: Try entering `192.168.1.255` or similar as the forward-to address? (`network_address | ~netmask`)

Comment: Alright, so my netmask is 255.255.254.0 and my router's IP is 192.168.1.1. Using an IP calculator (http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=192.168.1.1&mask1=255.255.254.0&mask2=) I now know that the broadcast address is 192.168.1.255. In my router there are several fields that need to be filled out for port forwarding. Could you tell me which goes where? Thanks in advance! These are the fields: PORT RANGE  -  LOCAL IP  -  LOCAL PORT  -  PROTOCOL (tcp/udp)  -  PROTOCOL NO.

Comment: @M0sthated: 9-9 / 192.168.1.255 / 9 / udp / ???

Answer (score 0):

The "Magic Packet" is really a broadcast frame, and broadcasts don't cross layer-3 boundaries (routers). You need to have a router which can do WoL for you, or you need to have a WoL server on the LAN.